# Cordova build ios `Cannot copy '../acorn/bin/acorn' to a subdirectory of itself, '../acorn/bin/acorn'.`

Tags: linux, macos, cordova

trying to `cordova build ios` on my Mac computer.
My project uses `Bootstrap` and it uses `Acorn`, as far as I know.
I get error: `Cannot copy '../acorn/bin/acorn' to a subdirectory of itself, '../acorn/bin/acorn'.`

Anyone knows how to solve this problem please?

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

I deleted `node_modules` folder from `platforms/ios/www` and now it works fine!

So much time wasted... :-(